Slicing a long and wide table across multiple pages
I used LaTeX during university for a while and got somewhat comfortable using LaTeX for automated document generation, however, I haved never deeply entered the rabbit whole of complex typesetting.
For my current endeaver, I have programatically generated tables that are both long and wide, i.e. many many rows + many many columns, too. For long tables (where full table width fits one page, e.g. when setting to landscape format), I usually use (what surprise) the longtables package.
Now, I have big tables, that I generate programatically using R (but the prep work shouldn't be a concern here, as I have tex questions, not R questions), I have the following setup:

Some header rows,
Several hundred content rows,
5-10 columns (we could consider the number of columns arbitrary), and
the first two columns - ideally - would be repeated within their respective slice

My current unsatiscatroy workaround is to slice up the table in R and output "unrelated" tables to a tex file.
Conceptual example:
Input Table:
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5
--------------
r1| *| *| *| *
r2| *| *| *| *
r3| *| *| *| *
r4| *| *| *| *
..............
rN| *| *| *| *

Output "sliced pages" in Pdf
Page 1:
C1|C2|C3|
---------
r1| *| *|
r2| *| *|
r3| *| *|

Page 2:
C1|C4|C5|
---------
r1| *| *|
r2| *| *|
r3| *| *|

Page 3:
C1|C2|C3|
---------
r4| *| *|
r5| *| *|
r6| *| *|

Page 4
C1|C4|C5|
---------
r4| *| *|
r5| *| *|
r6| *| *|

Page 5
C1|C2|C3|
---------
r7| *| *|
r8| *| *|
r9| *| *|

etc, ..., Last page:
C1|C4|C5|
---------
r.| *| *|
r.| *| *|
rN| *| *|

Questions:

Is there a way to slice wide tables within tex generation, similar to longtable?
Is there a way to include repeating columns?
Is there a "Z"-style slicing, i.e. create "horizontal slices" first, print them pagewise, and then proceed with the next rows?

Thank you in advance, I am very happy to be pointed in to a new direction that I don't know of yet.
Waldi.
I have tried to solve this outside of latex, but this is very cumbersome and not well typsetted. I tried to use different packages, but haven't found a straight-forward solution
